# use getApplicationContext to get another activity context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I would like to get the `Context` of another activity where I created an object (an adapter that contains a list of objects I need to display in the second activity).

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    private Context context = this;

    private GridView gridView;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;            

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(context);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mylayout2);
        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

Context context = this;

private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private GridView gridView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
   setContentView(R.layout.mylayout3);

   //what I want to do
   cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(manageCardContext); //I want this adapter to be the one in Activity1
   gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: it is very unlikely that you need to context of another activity. this seems like an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What are you trying to do in Activity2 with Activity1's context (I realize your displaying a list of objects in A2, but what that have to do w/ A1?)?

Comment: @SamusArin I created an adapter in Activity1 that contains a list of objects. With the adapter I can display the list of objects, but I need to display them in Activity2. That's why I thought about getting the context of Activity1 so I can pass it to the constructor of the adapter in Activity2

Comment: this question has probably been downvoted because it's not clear. Instead of asking for how to do a solution for a problem that's not explained, try to write your question explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @akari that would work if you made the object list public (or made an accessor to it), and then cast the context in A2 to A1 and reference this public member... (though I don't recommend this, as it is anemic) In A2.onCreate() do List<object> lo = ((A1)context).getObectList();

Answer (score 2):

> I created an adapter in Activity1 that contains a list of objects.

Only create an `Adapter` in the activity that will use the `Adapter`, and only use that `Adapter` in that activity.

> With the adapter I can display the list of objects, but I need to display them in Activity2

Then move the adapter-creation code from Activity1 to Activity2. Or, if you need the same sort of adapter in both places, copy the code, or have both activities inherit from some base class that has the adapter-creation code.

Comment: Actually both activities use the adapter. They both display the list of objects but I want the objects created and displayed in Activity1 to be displayed in Activity2, because objects are not created in Activity2

Comment: @akari I'd say just recreate the objects in activity2, it's most likely not worth the effort to just save from re-instantiating.

Comment: @akari: "Actually both activities use the adapter" -- at most, they could use the same adapter class. They cannot, and should not, be using the same adapter *instance*. "because objects are not created in Activity2" -- whatever these objects are need to be reachable from both activities, so they can create their own adapters. Or, do not use separate activities (e.g., use fragments in one activity).

Comment: @akari I'm using an MVC pattern, and every view (including fragments) gets its own View Model, which gets initialized and populated by their respective controllers. I never share references between the views, they are their own entity and get their own objects/collections/references, it will make your code much more modular.

Comment: Ok, I will create objects in Activity2 as you suggested CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

In similar vein to CommonsWare suggestion, I defined a public adapter class outside the Activity, just in a class file (sorry, this is C# code, but you should get the point if you already written yer adapter)

**CommonAdapter.java**

```
public class CommonAdapter : ArrayAdapter<AttachmentDetails>
{
    private readonly List<AttachmentDetails> _attachments;

    public CommonAdapter( Context context, List<AttachmentDetails> attachments )
        : base( context, 0, attachments )
    {       
        _attachments = attachments;
    }

    public override View GetView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and the instantiate wherever i need it

```
_recordAttachmentsGrid.Adapter = new CommonAdapter(this.ApplicationContext, Model.Attachments);
```